# Unfortunately launcher has stopped in android emulator

Tags: android

when i tried to change my emulator resolution 720X1280 and screen size 4 inch and density 213 after that when i am trying to launch the emulator its  showing **Unfortunately Launcher has stopped** note:My emulator is running on android 4.0 .plz help.

Thanks in advance

```
11-15 10:36:52.238: W/PackageManager(90): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.mail in package com.android.contacts
11-15 10:36:52.259: W/PackageManager(90): Unknown permission android.permission.ADD_SYSTEM_SERVICE in package com.android.phone
11-15 10:36:52.278: W/PackageManager(90): Unknown permission com.android.smspush.WAPPUSH_MANAGER_BIND in package com.android.phone
11-15 10:36:52.278: W/PackageManager(90): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH in package com.android.providers.calendar
11-15 10:36:52.278: W/PackageManager(90): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.cl in package com.android.providers.calendar
11-15 10:36:52.331: W/PackageManager(90): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.mail in package com.android.calendar
11-15 10:36:52.338: W/PackageManager(90): Not granting permission android.permission.SEND_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETED_INTENTS to package com.android.browser (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x9be45)
11-15 10:36:52.358: D/dalvikvm(234): GC_CONCURRENT freed 221K, 11% free 9063K/10119K, paused 3ms+5ms
11-15 10:36:52.420: W/PackageManager(90): Not granting permission android.permission.BIND_APPWIDGET to package com.android.widgetpreview (protectionLevel=3 flags=0x28be44)
11-15 10:36:52.438: W/PackageManager(90): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH in package com.android.settings
11-15 10:36:52.469: W/PackageManager(90): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH in package com.android.providers.contacts
11-15 10:36:52.469: W/PackageManager(90): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.cp in package com.android.providers.contacts
11-15 10:36:52.498: W/PackageManager(90): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.ACCESS_GOOGLE_PASSWORD in package com.android.development
11-15 10:36:52.498: W/PackageManager(90): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH in package com.android.development
11-15 10:36:52.498: W/PackageManager(90): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.ALL_SERVICES in package com.android.development
11-15 10:36:52.498: W/PackageManager(90): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.YouTubeUser in package com.android.development
11-15 10:36:52.518: W/PackageManager(90): Not granting permission android.permission.DEVICE_POWER to package com.android.deskclock (protectionLevel=2 flags=0x8be45)
11-15 10:36:53.128: D/MediaScannerReceiver(299): action: android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED path: /mnt/sdcard
11-15 10:36:53.679: D/dalvikvm(299): GC_CONCURRENT freed 235K, 11% free 8877K/9927K, paused 4ms+4ms
11-15 10:36:53.908: W/MediaScanner(299): Error opening directory '/mnt/sdcard/.android_secure/', skipping: Permission denied.
11-15 10:36:53.929: V/MediaScanner(299): pruneDeadThumbnailFiles... android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@413210b0
11-15 10:36:53.929: V/MediaScanner(299): /pruneDeadThumbnailFiles... android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@413210b0
11-15 10:36:54.039: D/Tethering(90): Tethering got CONNECTIVITY_ACTION
11-15 10:36:54.039: D/Tethering(90): MasterInitialState.processMessage what=3
11-15 10:36:54.478: D/dalvikvm(90): GC_CONCURRENT freed 605K, 12% free 11396K/12807K, paused 10ms+10ms
11-15 10:37:56.488: W/ThrottleService(90): unable to find stats for iface rmnet0
```

Here i have attached the screenshot

Comment: will [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854012/unknown-permission-while-developing-with-c2dm) help you

Comment: No its different not applicable for my problem.